# Ruby-on-Rails, Geocoding and IPv6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, geocoder

For years I have been determined a users location with the help of [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/), looking up the IPv4 address. By firing

request.location, I determined the location, and if the country was multilingual, I looked up the browser language setting to set the appropriate language. When I feed an IPv6 address to my Rails app, the IP address returns :::1, which isn't very helpful.

Unfortunately, IPv6 poses a challenge when it comes to determining a visitors location. Is there any proven way of working with IPv6 on Ruby-on-Rails?

I have googled my way through the internet but didn't come across a specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [`ipaddr`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) library. It supports `ipv4` and `ipv6`:

```rb
$ require 'ipaddr'
$ ipaddr = IPAddr.new "3ffe:505:2::1"
$ p ipaddr                   
#=> #<IPAddr: IPv6:3ffe:0505:0002:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>
$ p ipaddr.to_s              
#=> "3ffe:505:2::1"
```

If you want more advanced functionality, try the [`ipaddress`](https://github.com/ipaddress-gem/ipaddress) gem which also supports `ipv6`.

You can use `Geocoder.search()` to search by an `ipv6` address:

```rb
Geocoder.search(ipaddr)
Geocoder.search('2607:fea8:1360:f7d:dce7:b7f0:e0b6:1014')
```

Comment: `IPAddr` is part of stdlib and is not a gem.

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful :)